# How to reverse-proxy using apache web server to google cloud run services?

Tags: apache, nginx, nginx-config, mod-proxy, google-cloud-run

I have got some google cloud run service endpoints that are secured by HTTPS. I want to set up my apache webserver to reverse proxy into the services so that people using my defined URL get back the service response.
I have tried to use mod_proxy and mod_rewrite to proxy the service endpoint but it gives me 500 internal server error. How can it be done? Worst case please share an nginx solution for this.
Config I tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName hello.world.com
ServerAlias hello.world.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ https://helloworld-zxtb3wfs2a-de.a.run.app [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

BTW the endpoint is a website and not just a simple JSON response. Though even JSON responses are not working for me either.

Answer (score 2):

While rewriting the query back to the Cloud Run endpoint (*.run.app), you need to make sure you update `Host` header to match to that .run.app domain name as well. Otherwise, Cloud Run's frontend IP won't know where to send that.

Check this question  [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/802027/dynamically-set-requestheader-host-within-apache-mod-rewrite) on how to do this with mod_rewrite, and make sure you use `ProxyPreserveHost Off`.

Also since you're getting HTTP 500, make sure you check the application logs to see if there's something wrong with how the app handles this request.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have already deployed your cloud run service with --ingress internal option, so that no one can access Cloud Run without the reverse proxy.

Follow the below steps to create a reverse proxy in front of the cloud run service. You can skip Steps 2 - 5 if you are not installing self-signed SSL and you have your own SSL configured

1. Launch a Ubuntu Compute Engine and install apache2
2. Install self-signed SSL using

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
```

3. Update the SSL conf by replacing the below two lines in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

```
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
```

4. Enable necessary modules

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

5. Check the config and restart the server, then check whether you can load the https URL https://your-server-public-ip

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

6. Update /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf with this content, Don't forget to replace the CLOUD-RUN-URL

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://CLOUD-RUN-URL-as.a.run.app/
    ProxyPassReverse / https:///CLOUD-RUN-URL-as.a.run.app/
</VirtualHost>
```

7. Update /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf with this content, Don't forget to replace the CLOUD-RUN-URL

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLProxyEngine On
                ProxyPass / https://CLOUD-RUN-URL-as.a.run.app/
                ProxyPassReverse / https://CLOUD-RUN-URL-as.a.run.app/

                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

8. Enable few more modules

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

9. Check the config and restart the server

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

10. Now load the https URL https://your-server-public-ip again, this time you will get the response from cloud run